# Saving Android image state after dynamically changing the src

Tags: android, imageview, onrestoreinstancestate

I am developing an Android Application, where I have an imageView on a page and onLongClick it changes from Image A to Image B. However, when they leave the page the imageView goes back to Image A. How can I save the state (im guessing its done onpause, stop and destroy) so that it saves the current image src of the ImageView and load it up next time the page is accessed and created. I have never done data saving in Android..

Any simple data saving tutorial/example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines should help you out:

```
// Use a static tag so you're never debugging typos
private static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE = "image-resource";
private int image;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // if there's no bundle, this is the first time; use default resource
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        image = R.drawable.default;
    } else {
        // if there is a bundle, use the saved image resource (if one is there)
        image = savedInstanceState.getInt(IMAGE_RESOURCE, R.drawable.default);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Make sure you save the current image resource 
    outState.putInt(IMAGE_RESOURCE, image);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Make sure you set the image variable to the proper resource at the same time you change it in your click listener.

If you're looking to remember the state longer than this, look into [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: Hi Krylez, if the app is closed completely or they hit the back button out of the activity. Will this still retrieve the data? I mean, ofcourse if i put the calls on onDestroy / onStop etc. or does savedinstancestate lose the data when app is closed

Comment: The bundle is lost when you close the app. It only lives in memory, so when the Android OS closes your app, it's gone forever. The SharedPreferences will stick around even when your app is closed.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will need to use SharedPreferences then.